# Shortest path with file as input

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

I'm creating a graph taking a file as input and I want to calculate the shortest path, to do so I used SPF algorithm. I have a few file I can use to see if it works, and here comes the problem because it works until I try it with the biggest one (which has over 1 million vertex and 2 million edges), considering that the second for dimension has about 700k vertex and 100 million edges and with it it works just fine, what do you think the problem is? I just need some hint I really can't figure it out!
Please be patient with me, I'm new in this comunity and to coding in general, I'm just trying to learn and understand things properly...
It's returning error 3221225725

```
 // Function to compute the SPF algorithm
void shortestPathFaster(int S, int V)
{
    // Create array d to store shortest distance
    int d[V + 1];
 
    // Boolean array to check if vertex
    // is present in queue or not
    bool inQueue[V + 1] = { false };
 
    // Initialize the distance from source to
    // other vertex as INT_MAX(infinite)
    for (int i = 0; i <= V; i++) {
        d[i] = INT_MAX;
    }
    d[S] = 0;
 
    queue<int> q;
    q.push(S);
    inQueue[S] = true;
 
    while (!q.empty()) {
 
        // Take the front vertex from Queue
        int u = q.front();
        q.pop();
        inQueue[u] = false;
 
        // Relaxing all the adjacent edges of
        // vertex taken from the Queue
        for (int i = 0; i < graph[u].size(); i++) {
 
            int v = graph[u][i].first;
            int weight = graph[u][i].second;
 
            if (d[v] > d[u] + weight) {
                d[v] = d[u] + weight;
 
                // Check if vertex v is in Queue or not
                // if not then push it into the Queue
                if (!inQueue[v]) {
                    q.push(v);
                    inQueue[v] = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
 
    // Print the result
    print_distance(d, V);
}
```

Comment: please add a reproducible example of your code. Perhaps you are allocating too much memory on the stack, so try allocating on the heap using ```new```. Perhaps it is the other way around.

Comment: 3221225725 = 0xc00000fd = stack overflow.  Presumably, your algorithm is recursive, but *unless you post your code* we don't know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is most likely here:

```
int d[V + 1];
```

Firstly, variable length arrays are non-standard.  Secondly, if `V` is large you will overflow the stack.

Solution: replace this with [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).  `bool inQueue[V + 1]` should be treated similarly.

Also, replace `char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];` with [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).  You'll be glad you did.